# Regular Expression parsing interval

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression for parsing the interval, like `[22.3, sqrt(31))`

```
([\[\(])([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*|(\w*\([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\))|[+-]?oo)\W*?([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*|(\w*\([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\))|[+-]?oo)(\]\))
```

[image]

I'm looking to the scheme and confused: what's wrong exactly?
I also was wondered: can I split regex to string, like
regexfloat = '..'

and then combine them somehow into `re.compile` ?

Comment: You don't need to escape special characters inside brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ending `(\]\))` matches `])`, but not just one of the characters. You forgot to wrap them in `[ ]`.

```
([[(])([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*|(\w*\([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\))|[+-]?oo)\W*?([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*|(\w*\([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\))|[+-]?oo)([])])
```

Splitting up the pattern into several strings:

```
p_float = r'[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*'  # a number
p_func = r'\w*\(%s\)' % p_float    # function + number
p_inf = r'[+-]?oo'                 # infinity
p_value = r'%s|%s|%s' % (p_float, p_func, p_inf)
pattern = re.compile(r'([[(])(%s)\W*?(%s)([])])' % (p_value, p_value))
```

Comment: thanks alot. I was mentioned to use string sum instead, and forgot to put r toward each string as well. Thanks for the formatting, exactly what I needed.